# R repeat loop never end

Tags: r, repeat

I am running a poisson on a given matrix in `R`. And for some reasons, I would like to avoid any rowSums and colSums equal to 5 in example. I add `repeat` in my code to solve this issue but the run never end, even for small matrix.

Any ideas?
Thanks

```
mat <- matrix(c(seq(1,60,1)), nrow = 6, ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)

poiss <- function(mat) {
repeat{
pmat <-  rpois(length(mat), 1:3)
dim(pmat) <- dim(mat)
if(any(rowSums(pmat)) == 5 | any(colSums(pmat)) == 5) break
}
return(pmat)
}

p = poiss(mat)
```

Comment: `any` returns a logical vector of length one, so `any(...) == 5` makes little sense and will throw a warning. That's why you never break out of the `repeat` loop.

Comment: Did you mean to write `any(rowSums(pmat) == 5)`?

Comment: No if `any` rowSums or colSums equal to 5, it should restart the `rpois`function

Comment: Yes I understand, but that's not how `any` works. Have a look at `?any`. As I said in my previous comment if you want to test if *any* of the entries from `rowSums(pmat)` equals five, you need `any(rowSums(pmat) == 5)` (note the different bracketing compared to your code).

Comment: Sure!! I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped.